# Can this CStringArray be simplified using c++11? Is it worth it?

Tags: c++11, mfc

This might sound like a simple question but I am trying to learn the benefits of the new features in **c++ 11**. So, given this method:

```
CString CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::GetHtmlLanguageCode()
{
    CStringArray aryStrLangId;

    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("en"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("de"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("es"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("it"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("pl"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("fr"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("pt"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("nl"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("sv"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("sl"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("cs"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("fi"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("da"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("uk"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ru"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("tl"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ht"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("af"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("sq"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("zh-Hans"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("hr"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("tr"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("tw"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("sw"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("et"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ro"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("el"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("bg"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("mg"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ar"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("id"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("hi"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ta"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("vi"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("zu"));
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("guw")); // AJT v17.0.9 Gun 
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ln")); // AJT v17.0.9 Lingala
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("pt")); // AJT v17.0.9 Portuguese Portugal
    aryStrLangId.Add(_T("pa")); // AJT v17.1.3 Punjabi

    return aryStrLangId.GetAt(GetProgramLanguage());
}
```

It is not hard to maintain, but can it be changed to a simpler set of code? It is simply a list of strings and returns the value given an index position.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think MFC know anything about `std::initializer_list`, but you can elevate the new(old?) for-range loop:

```
CString CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::GetHtmlLanguageCode()
{
  constexpr const char* languages[] = { "en", "de", "es" ... };
  CStringArray aryStrLangId;
  for (auto lang : languages){
    aryStrLangId.Add(lang);
  }

   return aryStrLangId.GetAt(GetProgramLanguage());
}
```

this way you don't bloat your code with unnecessary calls to `Add`

Comment: Thought. If you have a languages array then we don't need the CStringArray. Just return at the index position of the const array.

Comment: Exactly. The above code could be rewritten without c++11.

Comment: the for range loop + auto + constexpr makes it c++11. you could have used old index-based iteration, but this is the simplest (and safest, as you need to know the array size) to do so.